# Alternative properties of clientX and clientY in IE11 which detects the browser back button..?

Tags: internet-explorer, button, browser, back

My requirement is like the user should be navigated to the logout page when he clicks on the IE 11 browser back button.

Tried this for 2 days but no progress.So, finally thought of posting it in here.

Please post a solution for this...

Comment: Please look into [how to write a proper question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) around here. Please show your best attempt. Please don't just come here expecting that others will write the code for you.

Comment: The common design pattern is to provide the user with a logout button on the page which executes server side code (asp.net form postback) to call session_end, clear any credential server variables and then to redirect the user back to the landing page or the login page. The back and forward buttons are not scriptable... they are for navigating the tabs' travel log.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this is by using onbeforeunload event.

```
<body onbeforeunload=”HandleBackFunctionality()”>

function HandleBackFunctionality()
 {
  if(window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0)
  {
     alert("Browser back button is clicked..."); // end the session here
  }
 }
```